# Android - Test Rotating Device in AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator

How do I test rotating an android device with an AVD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a keyboard command to do this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Look at the section "Controlling the Emulator".

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to change the screen orientation (rotate the screen) then Ctrl+F11 should work.